# Hardware accelerated gallery carousel with touch support

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, iscroll4

Looking for a sliding carousel with cross browser support down to IE7 and can support touch commands. At the moment I'm using a few lines of simple jQuery but that doesnt add the touch support nor the hardware acceleration where possible.

This has caught my interest http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/carousel/

Exactly what I am after. Although the touch effect does not need to work on desktop browsers, the next and prev buttons do and back to IE7. Do they currently / what can be done to make them.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this on multiple sites with great success. Highly customizable and works with touch.

[FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)